# jQuery - How many cells in a row

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way in jQuery to tell how many cells are in a selected row?  For example, I am iterating through the rows via:

```
$("#statsId > table tbody tr").each ( function() {
    var secondCol = $(this).find('td:nth-child(2)').html();
    var thirdCol= $(this).find('td:nth-child(3)').text();
```

and want to retrieve the second and third cell values.  However when I do this iteration the cell values are coming back null when I know they are not.  I thought if there was a way to verify the number of cells/columns in the selected row, I could at least verify that there are three cells in the selector.  Or perhaps my selector for "secondCol" and "thirdCol" is wrong.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this to test:

```
if( $(this).children('td').length >= 3 ) {
   ...
}
```

But also play with using `:eq()` as well:

```
var secondCol = $(this).find('td:eq(1)').html();
var thirdCol= $(this).find('td:eq(2)').text();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#myRow').children().size()
```

This is the most simple approach i can think of, but it's not infallable.

Comment: children allows for a filter selector, so you could do $('#row').children('td').size() and make sure you only get columns.

Answer (score 1):

```
var currentRow = <jQuery object for current row>;
var currentRowCellCount = $('td', currentRow).length;
```

This simply gives you access to the total number of `td` elements in a given row.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#statsId > table tbody tr").each(function() {
    var cells = $(this).find('td').size();
    ...
```